# Error parsing SOAP response

Tags: web-services, grails

I'm trying to parse a SOAP response from a web service. I'm using httpbuilder to do the request. Here is my code:

```
    def String WSDL_URL = 'http://ws.webgains.com/aws.php'
    def http = new HTTPBuilder( WSDL_URL , ContentType.XML )
    String soapEnvelope =
              """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                     xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <getFullUpdatedEarnings xmlns="http://ws.webgains.com/aws.php">
          <startDate>2013</startDate>
          <endDate>2013</endDate>
           <username>username</username>
           <password>pass</password>

        </getFullUpdatedEarnings>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>"""


            http.request( Method.POST, ContentType.XML ) {
                 body = soapEnvelope

                response.success = { resp, xml ->
                    println "XML was ${xml.Body.getFullUpdatedEarningsResponse.return.text()}"

                    def territories = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
                        xml.Body.getFullUpdatedEarningsResponse.return.text()
                    )

                }

                response.failure = { resp, xml ->
                    xml
                }
            }
```

When I try to parse the response I get a org.xml.sax.SAXParseException Content is not allowed in prolog.

Here is the output I'm getting from the web services:

```
3936713759987www.tikcode.com1367552013-05-13T15:04:482013-05-13T15:04:48Miniinthebox -     US46119566172850.060.8confirmednotcleared2013-05-13T14:58:33http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lightinthebox.com%2Fes%2F%3Flitb_from%3Daffiliate_webgainsEShttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fcom.publidirecta.widget%2Fpromocion%2FverPromocion%3Fpromocion%3D
```

If I use ContenTyp.TEXT the xml I'm getting is

```
[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>, <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn:http://ws.webgains.com/aws.php" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><env:Body xmlns:rpc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-rpc"><ns1:getFullUpdatedEarningsResponse env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"><rpc:result>return</rpc:result><return enc:itemType="ns1:fullLinesArray" enc:arraySize="1" xsi:type="ns1:fullReportArray"><item xsi:type="ns1:fullLinesArray"><transactionID xsi:type="xsd:int">39367137</transactionID><affiliateID xsi:type="xsd:int">59987</affiliateID><campaignName xsi:type="xsd:string">www.tikcode.com</campaignName><campaignID xsi:type="xsd:int">136755</campaignID><date xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-05-13T15:04:48</date><validationDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-05-13T15:04:48</validationDate><delayedUntilDate xsi:type="xsd:string"></delayedUntilDate><programName xsi:type="xsd:string">Miniinthebox - US</programName><programID xsi:type="xsd:int">4611</programID><linkID xsi:type="xsd:string">95661</linkID><eventID xsi:type="xsd:int">7285</eventID><commission xsi:type="xsd:float">0.06</commission><saleValue xsi:type="xsd:float">0.8</saleValue><status xsi:type="xsd:string">confirmed</status><paymentStatus xsi:type="xsd:string">notcleared</paymentStatus><changeReason xsi:nil="true"/><clickRef xsi:nil="true"/><clickthroughTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2013-05-13T14:58:33</clickthroughTime><landingPage xsi:type="xsd:string">http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lightinthebox.com%2Fes%2F%3Flitb_from%3Daffiliate_webgains</landingPage><country xsi:type="xsd:string">ES</country><referrer xsi:type="xsd:string">http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fcom.publidirecta.widget%2Fpromocion%2FverPromocion%3Fpromocion%3D</referrer></item></return></ns1:getFullUpdatedEarningsResponse></env:Body></env:Envelope>]
```

I'm fairly new to web services so If anyone have any ideas I really would appreciate any help

EDIT: Also tried with ws lite with the same results

Comment: SO, aparently,whom ever made the web services thought very funny to throw a "," between XML tags. Deleted the "," and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're parsing the response a second time.  Why are you using an XmlSlurper to parse the text of the `return` tag?  The elements under `return` are already parsed and can be accessed directly.